# Using iterate function to extract time series in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

The code below extracts average rainfall for each US county for one given day and send the table result to drive. Now, how can I use iterate function to extract a time series for one year for example?

```
 // load precip data (mm, daily )
var precipCollection = ee.ImageCollection('OREGONSTATE/PRISM/AN81d')
                    .select('ppt')   // select  precip band only
                    .filterDate('2017-01-01'); // e.g. one day
print(precipCollection, 'precipCollection');

//reduce the image collection 
var dailyPrecip = precipCollection.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
print(dailyPrecip);

// visualize annual precipitation
var precipPal = ['white','blue','red','pink'] // store palette as variable               
Map.addLayer(dailyPrecip, {min: 1, max: 100, palette: precipPal}, 'precip');

////////////////////////////////////

// load regions: counties from a public fusion table, removing non-conus states
// by using a custom filter
var nonCONUS = [2,15,60,66,69,72,78] // state FIPS codes that we don't want
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1ZMnPbFshUI3qbk9XE0H7t1N5CjsEGyl8lZfWfVn4')
        .filter(ee.Filter.inList('STATEFP',nonCONUS).not());
print(counties, 'counties');

// visualize
Map.addLayer(counties,{},'counties');  


// get mean precipitation values by county polygon
var countyPrecip = dailyPrecip.reduceRegions({
  collection: counties,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 4000 // the resolution of the prism dataset
});
print(countyPrecip);


// select features
var out = countyPrecip.select(['.*']);

// add a new column for date
out = out.map(function(feature){
return feature.set('date','2017-01-01');
});

// Table to Drive Export Example

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: out,
  description: 'precip_by_county',
  folder: 'GEE',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a try about [pkg_export](https://github.com/kongdd/gee_packages/blob/master/pkg_export.js).

```js
 // load precip data (mm, daily )
var precipCollection = ee.ImageCollection('OREGONSTATE/PRISM/AN81d')
                    .select('ppt')   // select  precip band only
                    .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2018-12-31'); // e.g. two year
print(precipCollection.limit(3), 'precipCollection');

// load regions: counties from a public fusion table, removing non-conus states
// by using a custom filter
var nonCONUS = [2,15,60,66,69,72,78]; // state FIPS codes that we don't want
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1ZMnPbFshUI3qbk9XE0H7t1N5CjsEGyl8lZfWfVn4')
        .filter(ee.Filter.inList('STATEFP',nonCONUS).not());
print(counties, 'counties');
Map.addLayer(counties, {}, 'counties');

/** pkg_export --------------------------------------------------------- */
var options = {
    reducers : ['mean'],  // 1th: non-buffer; 2th: buffer; Only one means no buffer
    buffer   : false,      // whether to use buffer
    list     : false, 
    folder   : '', // drive forder
    fileFormat: 'csv'      // 'csv' or 'geojson'
    // scale    : 1000
};

var pkgs = require('users/kongdd/pkgs:pkgs.js');
pkgs.spClipImgCol(precipCollection, counties, "precipCollection", options);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8221ae9a4ae68a42f6b775a2cf84d6b2

Comment: it works well, but I wonder in this case how to only save some columns (i.e. select only the columns of interest or remove others)

Comment: You can select columns by selecting bands in `counties` and `precipCollection` first. If that works for you, please consider accept my answer. I need the score to vote.

Comment: Dear Dongdong Kong, your repo is not active : users/kongdd/pkgs

Comment: it should work. Could you post your GEE link?